# Problem with SVN in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, subversive, smartsvn

I am using Smart SVN for committed my code to server. I have faced some problem, some of the classes are there in my project work copy and the server also. When i open that project file and i missed some classes and images in the xcode file. But all the files are in the project work copy, when opened that file some files are missing only in Xcode. After that, i have to drag those missing my file from my local copy to Xcode file, then it works fine. In the server all files are there, but i donno why it is not coming to Xcode folder.

Answer (score 1):

@pugal : Always update your project before start working on the last commit , so that you can identify changes , then if any files missing , add & then commit them .

Better try to use xcode.inbuilt SCM to track all progress in your project itself or use command line tools in terminal if you interested .

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, Xcode doesnt show all the files that are in the folder! they have to be inside xcode too! in the main project file there is some XML that XCode use to control those files! so if you have any file just in the folder xcode wont display it! You always have to drag and drop to it! However after u project is with all files inside you just have to commit your project file and should be fine afterwards!

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project file is also committed and updated.
You and your teammates should always commit your project file after you added some files into your project.